# What type of files to commit versus ignore in a Git repository?

Tags: git, gitignore

So I want use both GitHub and Bitbucket as repos (depending if I want something to be public versus private) and a lot of my work also includes LaTeX work (so there are .tex, .png, and .pdf files) as well as speed tests (so I may have .csv, and .Rdata files).

I'm having a hard time determining what kinds of files should make their way into my repos versus which should be linked to inside the README.mds.

Does anyone have any simple philosophies or hard-and-fast rules they'd like to share?

Comment: Ignore generated files, most of the time.

Comment: ignore config files that contain sensitive data like DB credentials.

Comment: Agreed with Matt Ball, but including the "most of the time". For rarely changing generated files that require special tools to regenerate, it may be more appropriate to make an exception.

Comment: @MattBall, does that mean, for example, ignoring the .pdf output of a .tex file?

Comment: Also, what about a .csv file that's useful for benchmarking the speed of your code?

Comment: A down vote and no comment? Real lame.

Comment: @StevieP: It happens. Yes, it's annoying, but you'll find it's not worth worrying about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally ignore binary files, and especially large files. Git doesn't do large or binary file tracking with aplomb like SVN can.

If you must, exceptions can be made for small files (i.e. png's) as long as they aren't changing too much.

Comment: I'm a newbie. Can you tell me when I'd know that something is a binary file? For example, are generated .pdf's binary files?

Comment: `file -b -i file_name` is a good linux / mac command-line command, that should return the mime type of your file. source: [linux + identify binary file](http://superuser.com/questions/185542/linux-identify-binary-file)

Generally, it will tell you when you're dealing with a text / ASCII file. You can (almost) assume that anything else is binary.

Answer (score 3):

Typically you'll want your repo to contain only files from which everything else can be automatically generated.

For example, if it's a C program, you'll want `*.c` and `*.h` files, plus any Makefiles, but not object files and executables. The idea is that someone can clone your repo, follow your build instructions, and recreate everything needed to use your project.

Text vs. binary is not always the best rule to follow. For example, a `.png` image file that's generated automatically doesn't need to be in the repo, but if it's an icon file that you built manually (and that your program depends on), it should be in the repo.

This isn't a hard and fast rule. Sometimes it might be convenient to include generated binaries. For example (assuming an application), if you package the installable application into, say, a `.zip`, `.tgz`, or `.msi` file, it's reasonable to provide that in the repo (probably in a separate directory). If you include something like that that's intended to be the *current* version of the application, be sure it's up to date before you commit and push.